# Is there an easy way to find out what bridge an interface is connected to?

Tags: network-bridge

The vcore network simulator creates bridges to interconnect interfaces on virtual router simulations, and I need to be able to add an IP address for the host on whichever bridge 'dummy0' is connected to. I have no control over the names of the bridges created, and the bridge names change each time the simulation runs. The output from brctl does show the information I need; but in a form that would require a (Perl?) script to parse. There used to be bridge information under /proc, but that seems to have been deprecated. Anyone know of a simple way?

Comment: See if [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40560/how-to-know-if-a-network-interface-is-tap-tun-bridge-or-physical) helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - that gave clues. I can find the name of the bridge that dummy0 is connected to by means of e.g.:

```
$ find /sys/devices/virtual/net -name 'lower_dummy0'
/sys/devices/virtual/net/**b.28354.f9**/lower_dummy0
```